# Switching Employers After Traveling on Blue Card Visa and Arriving in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card

I have a job offer (Blue Card) which I have accepted. However I have recently received another job offer which is extremely exciting and I want to switch over to this. Now since the COVID, visa process takes painstakingly long (it took me 8 months from offer to getting visa). I am thinking on traveling on the existing visa and then switching over after arriving.

Is it possible to travel to Germany on Blue Card visa and then switch over to new employer without joining the initial employer?

Comment: We need to know what exactly your visa states. I would suggest that one's employer might be mentioned on the visa. If it is not mentioned **and visa allows working**, then one might start working at more or less any employer. If it is mentioned, then one need to get the permission for new employer before the first working day.

Comment: This is what is written on visa. 

ErWerbstätig -- KEIT BEI XXXX NACH § 18B (2) 
AUFENTHG; AUFENTHALTS ANZEIGE NACH EINREISE

Here XXXX is company name.

Comment: Yes, your visa only allows working by that company, not by any other one.

Comment: Only after 2 years of a Blue Card can you change your employer without requiring authorization of the Immigration office.

Comment: So answering the original question, in such situation one can of course travel to Germany and switch over to new employer without joining the first one. But it will not be possible to start working for new employer until you get a permission from immigration office.