# German issued blue card visa, employment not yet started and found better job with different employer, am I allowed to join without informing?

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, blue-card, indian-citizens

As the title states, I have a blue card visa issued by german embassy in india valid from March to Septemeber 2022, my visa does not state my company name anywhere as far as I can see. I found a better employer and I can start with them from March itself. However i am not sure of what to do. My visa remarks reads the following
"18B ABS. 2s. 1 AUFENTHG  BLUE KARTE EU" then the next line reads "AUFENTHALTSDAUER ENTSPRICHT GULTIGKEIT"
Am I free to join the new employer directly upon landing in germany and do the anmeldung etc with them or do I need to inform the embassy in my country of the change and start the whole process?
Please advise

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21106/switching-employers-after-traveling-on-blue-card-visa-and-arriving-in-germany

Comment: In your application, you gave the company name and contract details. Based on that information the immigration office in Germany granted the visa that the consulate issued. You must inform the immigration office in Germany about the new employer, so that they can check if all of the conditions are still fulfilled.

Comment: The visa was issued by the German embassy not the immigration officer. I am not in Germany, I'm still in my home country.

Comment: A consulate will only issue such a visa **after** the authorisation of the immigration office. It is the immigration office that makes the decision.